# Color scheme/Theme used in Plain tasks sublime plugin

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, code-editor, sublime-text-plugin

Can anyone please tell me, whats the color scheme that is being used by [Plain Tasks](https://github.com/aziz/PlainTasks)? Any sublime color scheme plugin that you may aware of would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go through the files on Github, you'll find that there are several `.hidden-tmTheme` files. These are formatted just like regular `.tmTheme` color scheme files, except that they are specific to a certain plugin, and are not visible through the `Preferences -> Color Scheme` menu. If you'd like to use one of them as a regular color scheme, simply copy the file to your `Packages/User` directory and rename it to end with `.tmTheme` instead of `.hidden-tmTheme`. It will now be available via `Preferences -> Color Scheme -> User`.